# `brew upgrade <package>`: "<package> cannot be built with any available compilers"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew

For example, I tried to run `brew upgrade ruby-build`.

That failed with error:

```
CompilerSelectionError: ruby-build cannot be built with any available compilers.
Install GNU's GCC
  brew install gcc
```

When I ran `brew install gcc` , I got:

```
Warning: Building gcc from source:
  The bottle needs the Xcode CLT to be installed.
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  CompilerSelectionError: gcc cannot be built with any available compilers.
Install GNU's GCC
  brew install gcc
```

How can I upgrade `ruby-build` via `brew`?

Comment: Have you installed XCode Command Line Utilities?  You might just need to run `xcode-select --install` in the terminal.

Comment: A ["MAC Address"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) is a specific thing. A "Mac" is a type of computer. Careful with case.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I ran this command and it now works:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Worked for me. The command I was trying was brew install --build-from-source gcc

Answer (score 1):

I had to reset xcode to the default command line tools path with
`sudo xcode-select -r`
for this to work